# Wordpress Login Dashboard too many redirects

Tags: wordpress

Just added a 301 redirect code inside my *htaccess* file and now I can't even access my own dashboard for WordPress. It says:

> This page isn’t working

*website.com* redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I already cleared everything, even my advanced settings for cache and cookies.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have no ftp access on this also :(

Comment: **Make a copy** of the old `htaccess` then delete it. Once done, login to dashboard and reset your permalinks to generate a new one.

Comment: how can i do that if i can't access the dashboard nor the cpanel of the website? :(

Comment: I know where did I go wrong, on what line but the thing is I can't login to it anymore since it creates redirect loop.

Comment: Why can you not access cpanel? cpanel is independent of your wordpress url.

Comment: Is there any way that I can login in my dashboard rather than the cpanel, sir?

Comment: Not that I know of. Your hosting provider might be able to help.